# What changes are required to publish an Emergency app having SMS alerts in Google play according to new SMS permission policy

Tags: android, google-play

I am working on an Emergency app that will send SMS alerts.When i try to publish it ,it shows a form and i need to select option from it. Acc to my app i have selected "Physical Safety/Emergency SMS alerts App" option and submit the app,but Problem is  Google rejects my submision. I have  SEND_SMS permission in Manifest file and that too comes under Exception category of updated permission policy.What should be done inside code or on play console to make it live?

I have gone through all the queries regarding SMS permission or Google permission policy ,but not able to find any solution that can work for me.All are providing same google permission policy [link](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/).

Comment: That is what i am asking here.I have read the policy updates regarding SMS permissions . I think my app comes under Exception section of policy given in https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/ .If my understanding is wrong then what else should i try to  remove this rejection.

Answer (score 4):

Don't expect any approval.

I am the author of [Medical ID](https://medicalid.app/) app, with more than 100k active users. The app includes an SMS alert as a core feature. I submitted the exception form multiple times, including a video, step-by-step explanations, etc. and the exception was rejected multiple times.

How can an emergency app with a clear and core SMS alert feature not meet their  SAFETY_EMERGENCY_ALERT guidelines?

That's a great question they don't want to answer. What is really crazy is that real people review submitted forms and messages. However, and most probably for legal reasons, they answer with a very generic message so that nobody can take any actions and claim an arbitrary rejection.

What I noticed is that only highly popular apps have a chance to get the approval. For instance, [Tasker got an approval](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/acheqp/update_sms_and_call_permissions_success/) even though their usage is completely generic!

Comment: I thinks you build your app by Java,Because Google send Notifications to Google play Developers about new policies for dealing with Native and non-Native Apps

Comment: Thanku @Laurent, I have sent my app for their approval by filling that enquiry  form .They publish it once but not accepting any update for the app.

Comment: SMSRetriever API can help in such cases

Comment: We do not need any permission for SMS or call and no need for getting permission from play store

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview helping link for those who are still struggling with google play store permission policy

Comment: Your link is specific to a given use case: user auth verification... which does not address op use case.

Comment: Yes . Sorry thats right. this link is only useful to read sms not to send.

Comment: Hey Laurent. It does appear your app finally got approval to send SMS (congrats!). Would you mind sharing how you were, finally, able to achieve this?  Thank you.

Comment: I updated the app onboarding to clarify usage, added an explanation popup before each action requesting a permission, updated the app description on the Playstore to mention that SMS sending is a core feature, and made a short and clear video for Google's reviewers. This required a lot of work, but since I fall exactly in one of their exception lists I get approved. Note that the "approved" state is really obscure. You see a green tick like when you submit your first request but you never receive an email for approval. It seems to work the other way: you get an email for rejections only.