# My App does not qualify for use of the requested permissions Google new policy

Tags: android, android-permissions, publishing

I published my app on google play store , and before that I submitted a Permissions Declaration Form , and after few days I got a message from google play support :

{ We reviewed your app and found that it does not qualify for use of the requested permissions for the following reasons:

The declared functionality {DEFAULT_DIALER, CALLER_ID_DETECTION_BLOCKING, DEFAULT_SMS}  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.

Your app will be published to Google Play, but a compliant version of your app must be submitted by March 9, 2019, or your app will be removed.
}

My app goals : - Auto blocking for incoming calls
               - Auto sending sms for missed calls (determined by the user)
               - Auto sending sms at specific time

so what I need to do to avoid  removing my app , what are the core functionalities that I must selected for my app.

My app name is : 'Auto SMS Sender/Call Blocker , you can find it on the play store : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mhd.engineer.com.callmanagement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- I think the problem in your
- Privacy Policy
- you must demonstrate all things about your App

Comment: what are the appropriate core functionalities that I must select for my app in google play console when I want to add a next release?

Comment: Mohamad , I try it but it not working ,,review Google Policies before replace your new release and review also your Signed Apk

Comment: this Post clear your problem with Google new Policies with SMS Apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414923/what-changes-are-required-to-publish-an-emergency-app-having-sms-alerts-in-googl